# Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

What is the correct way to center figures and tables (`figure`, `table`)?

```
\begin{center}
...
\end{center}
```

or

```
\begin{centering}
...
\end{centering}
```

Comment: Definitely never put the `center` environment around the `figure` environment! See [Tables and sections get misplaced](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15507/tables-and-sections-get-misplaced/15511#15511). (Not that I say Yiannis did this)

Answer (score 411, accepted):

The correct way is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
... (Code for pictures, captions) ...
\end{figure}
```

`\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` inside a `figure` environment will result in (generally unwanted) additional vertical space.

Note that while `\centering` produces proper spacing, manually adding this command to every `figure` environment (and to every `table` and custom-made float) is tedious and goes against the idea of separating the content of a document from the format. Even better ways are to add the following to your document preamble (thanks to egreg for the tip):

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
```

or to load the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package which allows to control the justification of float contents from the preamble (with `objectset=centering` as default).

Comment: Also note that `\centering` is a declaration, not an environment. That `\begin{centering}` works is an unfortunate consequence of the way environments work internally in LaTeX: The environment foo essentially consist of two macros `\foo` and `\endfoo` which are called by `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}`, respectively (along with some error checking, such as proper nesting). But since `\endfoo` is called via `\csname endfoo\endcsname`, that macro doesn't actually have to exist. This means that even stuff such as `$\begin{alpha}\end{alpha}$` works (but should of course not be used).

Comment: There's also the more esoteric `\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering` which, of course, should be preceded by `\makeatletter` and followed by `\makeatother`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `floatrow` package which looks very, very powerful (I should have found that before, now changing all figure/table definitions in my thesis will be quite some work).  

However, the documentation is so long and there are so many possibilities of configuration, that it will be very hard to figure out the best setup.. is there a tuturial with a "recommended" setup for a twopage thesis? :-(

Comment: @Villemoes So why so many LaTeX editors use snippets for insert figures that use yet the `center` environment instead the `centering` declaration?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for tikz-cd.  What should be modified?

Comment: For use with `IEEEtran`, `\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering` is ineffective since `\figure` redefines `\@floatboxreset`. I use `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd{\figure}{\normalsize}{\normalsize\centering}{}{}`.

Comment: @bers This command is not working anymore. How to fix it?

Comment: @whatsname `\documentclass[onecolumn]{IEEEtran}\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\figure}{\normalsize}{\normalsize\centering}{}{}\begin{document}\begin{figure}Test\end{figure}\end{document}` is working fine for me. No errors, and "Test" is centered.

Answer (score 63):

This is a (very late!) supplement to [lockstep's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2652/) which just offers a visual demonstration of the difference between the use of `\centering` and the `center` environment within `figure` environments.

Each page shows 2 figures, one using `\centering` and one using `center`. The differences in spacing are the result of ordering the two `figure` environments differently. On the first page, `\centering` is used first and the `center` environment second, while on the second page, this order is reversed.

The results clearly show inappropriate spacing for the lower figure (first page) and the upper figure (second page) i.e. for whichever figure uses `center` rather than `\centering`.

`showframe` is used to show the overall page layout.

[image: illustration of differences between <code>\centering</code> and <code>center</code> environment inside <code>figure</code> environments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure with centering}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure in center environment}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[3]
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure in center environment}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[4]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure with centering}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Finally, compare two pages with two figures each. The first page includes figures which use `\centering`, while the second includes figures which use the `center` environment.

[image: Further comparisons]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure with centering}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure with centering}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[3]
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure in center environment}
  \end{figure}
  \kant[4]
   \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Figure in center environment}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

Since this thread gave birth to [a little misunderstanding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508123/101651), I would like to add a note.

As the other answers say, `center` environment should **never** be used **within a `figure` or `table` environment**, you should use `\centering` instead:

[image]

But if your table or image are not floating, that is you would like to have them exactly where you put them, i.e. they are **not** within a `figure` or a `table` environment, you can use a `center` environment without problems. It is equivalent to a `table` or a `figure` environment with the `H` option of `float` package.

If you would like to add a caption, you can use `\captionof` from `\caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
You can use \texttt{center} environments here, because they are not within a floating one:
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{A non-floating table within a \texttt{center} environment}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
         Ducks & Lions \\
         \midrule
         1 & 2 \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{A non-floating figure within a \texttt{center} environment}
\end{center}

They are equivalent to a \texttt{table} or \texttt{figure} environment with the \texttt{H} option of \texttt{float} package:
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{A non-floating table with \texttt{H} option}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
         Ducks & Lions \\
         \midrule
         1 & 2 \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}    \caption{A non-floating figure with \texttt{H} option}
\end{figure}

Just to show the also the lists works:
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about flushleft and flushright a table or a figure?

Comment: @BlackMild There are `flushleft` and `flushright` environments, as well as `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` commands